Pytesseract OCR recognizes "o" as "0"
I'm trying to read text on this image using pytesseract library.
original-screenshot.png
Here is my code:
path = 'original-screenshot.png'

image = cv2.imread(path)
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
image = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(image, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,
                                cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 101, -69)

cv2.imwrite('screenshot.png', image)

custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 7 -l eng -c tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghigklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_config)

print(text)

Processed Image:
screenshot.png
Text Output:
01991f5
Expected Output:
o1991f5

Not sure, but you're missing "j" in your alphabet.

If you want accuracy like that, you need something trained to the specific font.

@Phix, Thank you, but it didn't fix the issue

@OrangeDog Where can I find these models and how to use them? The font is Source Sans Pro

Make them yourself, usually. The question is too broad for here.

Google found me this: How to train Tesseract 4.00.  If you need more, look at other search results for tesseract training.

You have to play with the image size. But your picture is really on limit. If you increase the size the 5 will be recognized as a S. I used your poted original-screenshot.png:
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
 
img = cv2.imread('o.png',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
(thresh, blackAndWhiteImage) = cv2.threshold(grayImage, 150, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# resize image
scale_percent = 6.4 # percent of original size
width = int(blackAndWhiteImage.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
height = int(blackAndWhiteImage.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
dim = (width, height)
resized = cv2.resize(blackAndWhiteImage, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)

# OCR resized Black & White image
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'--psm 13 --oem 3 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz01234567890' 
tex = pytesseract.image_to_string(resized, config=custom_config)
print(tex)

# Display resized image
cv2.imshow("resized", resized)
 
# Save the resized image
cv2.imwrite("Resized_Image.jpg", resized)
 
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Result:


@ThunderFound Please accept my answer, if it answers your question!
